# min-height for tables without affecting thead and tbody in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, height, tablelayout

I have a table that I want to set a `min-height` on.
As far as I can tell though, `min-height` does not work on tables, and in fact, you have to set a `height` on the table instead.

That's fine except for the fact that when I set a `height` on a table that has a `thead`, `tbody` and a `tfoot`, all with one row each, the height of each of the three sections is set to a third of the total height in Firefox only, which I don't want.
Chrome and IE (tested back to IE8) both keep the `thead` and `tfoot` the original height and stretch only the `tbody`.

I want the `thead` and `tfoot` to remain their original height and then have the `tbody` only stretch the remainder of the `height` in Firefox as well (just like in Chrome and IE).

Is there any way to do this in Firefox?
Thank you.

**Edit**:

Here's what I want:

[image: desired_layout]

And here's what I actually get in Firefox:

[image: actual_layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could assign a `height` value to the `th` and/or `td` inside `thead` and `tfoot`, see the demo below:

```css
table {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
thead {
    background: crimson;
}
tbody {
    background: orange;
}
tfoot {
    background: green;
}
thead th, thead td, tfoot th, tfoot td {
    height: 0; /*or any height*/
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header content 1</th>
            <th>Header content 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Body content 1</td>
            <td>Body content 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Footer content 1</td>
            <td>Footer content 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, (begrudgingly) I just arrived at the same conclusion. I hate to set a set height for the `th`s and `td`s in the header and footer of the table, but all the same, it is what it is, and it looks fine in all browsers now. Annoying, but just the way it is on the web these days, I guess. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HartleySan :P the height value on th and td is really working like min-height, there should not be any problem on that.